# Java Iterate through a HashMap<?, List<?>> and for each Key count how many Values the Key has

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

I'm having problems on how to tackle this since I know a map has no specific order. I would think that you would iterate over the map's Keys and then check the value count by getting the size of the LinkedList since the Values to the Key are held in a LinkedList I can just call a size or length call for the LinkedList, but my main question is how to get inside the HashMap with an iterator first to do this?

Comment: A map associates each key in the map with exactly one value.

Comment: I think you're confused. I think the hash buckets for a `HashMap` are implemented using some sort of linked list, but that's for keys with the same `hashCode`, not for values with the same key. As @immibis says, there is only one value for each key.

Comment: There is one value for a key, but the value is a LinkedList which gets around that.

Comment: If you're referring to a `Map<?, List<?>>` you should specifically say so.

Comment: It says the values are held in a LinkedList in the main topic from ever since I posted this

Comment: Describing your Map correctly would put it beyond doub,t but OK, if you can't or won't make it clear, I will. You've confused all the other commenters here, and an answerer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have something like this :

```
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You can just iterate very simply through all the values you have.

```
    for (List<Integer> values : map.values()){
        System.out.println(values.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An iterator over all the entries of a map can be done as follows in Java:

```
for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  Key k = entry.getKey();
  Value v = entry.getValue();
  // do something with k,v
}
```

However, a map can only contain at most one value associated with a key. So, if using a map of lists to associate multiple values, the list would be accessed simply through `get`.